# OperationalError at / no such column: accounts_customer.user_id

Tags: python, django

i have been following this tutorial I was going smoothly but i got an error .i am not sure how to resolve it .I added onetoone relationship to the customer with user model.And now got this user.
**`models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import RegexValidator
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class customer(models.Model):
    user=models.OneToOneField(User,null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   
    name=models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    phone_no=models.CharField(max_length=200, validators 
    [RegexValidator(r'^\d{1,10}$')],null=True)
    email=models.EmailField(max_length=200,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class tag(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class products(models.Model):
   
    categories=[
    ('indoor','indoor'),
    ('outdoor','outdoor')
    ]
    name=models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    price=models.FloatField(null=True)
    manufacturedate=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True,null=True)
    description:models.TextField(null=True)
    categories=models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,choices=categories)
    tag=models.ManyToManyField(tag)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class order(models.Model):
    
    status=[
        ('pending','pending'),
        ('out of stock','out of stock',),
        ('Delivered',('Delivered'))
    ]
    ordered_date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status=models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,choices=status)
    customer=models.ForeignKey(customer,null=True,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    product=models.ForeignKey(products,null=True,on_delete=models.SET_NULL)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.product.name
```

I am really confused . I am stuck here for a while.It was all fineuntil i added onetoone relationship.

**views.py**

enter code here
from multiprocessing import context
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from .models import *
from .forms import CreateCustomer,CreateOrder,CreateUser
from .filters import FilterSearch

```
from django.contrib.auth import logout,login,authenticate
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from .decorators import allowed_users,admin_only



def registeruser(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('home')
    else :   
        form=CreateUser()
        if request.method=='POST':
            form=CreateUser(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                user=form.save()
                
                group=Group.objects.get(name='customer')
                user.groups.add(group)

                login(request,user)

                return redirect('home')
        context={'form':form}
        return render(request,'accounts/registeruser.html',context)

    

def loginuser(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('home')
    else :
        if request.method=='POST':
            username=request.POST.get('username')
            password=request.POST.get('password')
            user=authenticate(request,username=username,password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request,user)
                return redirect('home')
            else:
                messages.info(request,"Something went wrong!!")
    context={}
    return render(request,'accounts/login.html',context)

@login_required(login_url='login')
def logoutuser(request):
    logout(request)
    return redirect('login')

@login_required(login_url='login')  

@admin_only
def home(request): 
    customers=customer.objects.all()
    orders=order.objects.all()
    total_customers=customers.count()
    total_orders=orders.count()
    delivered=orders.filter(status='Delivered').count()
    pending=orders.filter(status='pending').count()



    context= {'customers':customers,'orders':orders,'total_customers':total_customers,
    'total_orders':total_orders,'delivered':delivered,
    'pending':pending }

    return render(request,'accounts/home.html',context)

@login_required(login_url='login')
@allowed_users(allowed_roles=['customer'])
def userprofile(request):
    return render(request,'accounts/userprofile.html',context)

@login_required(login_url='login')
def product(request):

    return render(request,'accounts/products.html')

@login_required(login_url='login')
@allowed_users(allowed_roles=['customer'])
def Customer(request,pk):
    Customer=customer.objects.get(id=pk)
    orders=Customer.order_set.all()
    if request.method=='GET':
        filterset=FilterSearch(request.GET,queryset=orders)
        orders=filterset.qs

    order_count=orders.count()
    context={'Customer':Customer,'orders':orders,'order_count':order_count 
    ,'filterset':filterset}
    return render(request,'accounts/customers.html',context)

@login_required(login_url='login') 
@allowed_users(allowed_roles=['customer'])  
def createcustomer(request):
    form=CreateCustomer()
    if request.method=='POST':
        form=CreateCustomer(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('home')

    context={'form':form}
    return render(request,'accounts/customerform.html',context)

@login_required(login_url='login')
@allowed_users(allowed_roles=['customer'])
def createorder(request):

    form=CreateOrder()
    if request.method=='POST':
    
        form=CreateOrder(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('home')
    context={'form':form}
    return render(request,'accounts/orderform.html',context)

@login_required(login_url='login')
@allowed_users(allowed_roles=['customer'])
def updateOrder(request,pk):
    orders=order.objects.get(id=pk)
    form=CreateOrder(instance=orders)
    if request.method=='POST':
        form=CreateOrder(request.POST,instance=orders)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('home')
    context={'form':form}
    return render(request,'accounts/orderform.html',context)

@login_required(login_url='login')
@allowed_users(allowed_roles=['customer'])
def deleteOrder(request,pk):
    orders=order.objects.get(id=pk)
    if request.method=='POST':
        orders.delete()
        return redirect('home')
    context={'order':orders}

    return render(request,'accounts/deleteorder.html',context)
```

I would really appreciate your help

**urls.py**

```
enter code here
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns=[
    path('registeruser/',views.registeruser,name="registeruser"),
    path('login/',views.loginuser,name="login"),
    path('user/',views.userprofile,name='userprofile'),
    path('logout/',views.logoutuser,name="logout"),
    path('',views.home,name="home"),
    path('products/',views.product,name='product'),
    path('customers/<str:pk>/',views.Customer,name='customer'),
    path('Createcustomers/',views.createcustomer,name='createcustomer'),
    path('Createorder/',views.createorder,name='createorder'),
    path('updateorder/<str:pk>/',views.updateOrder,name='updateorder'),
    path('deleteorder/<str:pk>/',views.deleteOrder,name='deleteorder'),
]
```

Comment: have you migrated after adding oneTooneField

Comment: yes i did ,but still error is showing

Comment: Could u reduce your question to only show the needed part to solve the problem, in `views`

Answer (score 0):

I understand what is an error.
you check id using `Customer=customer.objects.get(id=pk)` in customer function in views.py.

But you write `path('customers/<str:pk>/',views.Customer,name='customer')`
in urls.py.

It means you check "Id (integer value)" in your customer function but you pass pk but as a string value. so python consider as a string value not a integer value.

so you should have change "customers/int:pk/" in urls.py file.

then run server and run it.

Comment: i tried that too but it didn't solve error

Answer (score 0):

Simply you delete all your migration folders and migrate manually by runing below command:

```
python manage.py makemigrations appname

python manage.py sqlmigrate appname 0001 

python manage.py migrate
```

Try above command and see if this is solves your error

Comment: sry but it didn't work either

Answer (score 0):

every customers doesn't have user in database. because you have added it latter. Go to admin panel. And add onetoone field user manually from database.Then it should work. Another method is you have to hadle exception if there is null or id in relationship.

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete the `db.sqlite3` file or the database you are using

   - if not `db.sqlite3`: recreate the database after
2. Delete all Migrations
3. Run `python manage.py makemigrations` + `python manage.py migrate`
4. Continue Dev

the debugging steps are to try #3 and if that doesn't work follow steps 1-3*

and remember: Dev dbs are easily trash-able.

***Note:** In older Projects that have a Production version, skip #2